# AddressBook in Tab

Tags: ios, addressbook

I have a tabbed application.
I want AddressBook to appear in one of my tabs.
The following code works, but AddressBook appears not in the tab itself, but in the entire view of the application.

```
_addressBookController = [[ABPeoplePickerNavigationController alloc] init];

[_addressBookController setPeoplePickerDelegate:self];

[self presentViewController:_addressBookController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Answer (score 0):

The following code helped me:

```
[self.view addSubview:_addressBookController.view];
[self addChildViewController:_addressBookController];
[_addressBookController didMoveToParentViewController:nil];
```

instead of

```
[self presentViewController:_addressBookController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

I also replaced

```
[_addressBookController dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
```

with

```
[_addressBookController.view removeFromSuperview];
```